# What is the X version in 12.04?

Tags: xorg

Just a matter of curiosity, I was wondering what version of X comes with Precise. Problem is, it reports (X -version, as well as XProtocolVersion/XProtocolRevision) that it is X11R0.

This was a fresh install from the Xubuntu 12.04 install CD.

Is this a configuration issue on my system, or a bug, or is the revision a don't-care now?

Merely curious -- doesn't seem to break anything.

Answer (score 2):

The [**X protocol version**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System_protocols_and_architecture) is reported as:

```
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
```

The software itself is specifically the [**X.Org X Server**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.Org_Server) (there are others, like [XFree86](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XFree86)), and it's version is reported as:

```
X.Org X Server 1.11.3
```

(Full output of `X -version` from my system [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1024292/).)

Comment: Same here. Also, looking at actual files, there's things like libxcb-glx.so.0.0.0 which just muddies the water :) So maybe this distro takes from the not-yet-released X11R7.7 (7.6 was released in 2010), although versions of the libs don't seem to agree with anything at xorg.freedesktop.org... Ah, well. Not a big deal. :)

Comment: @ikmac What's confusing? All these versions seem to make sense. What disagrees with xorg.freedesktop.org?

Comment: Revision 0 makes no sense.

Comment: Hasn't X11R0 been obsolete for decades? Current version from xorg is X11R7.6